# Python - dictionary iteration and replacement fails on same case each time

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I loop through a dictionary. The keys are the 'old values' that I want to replace with the 'new values', the values in the dictionary.

I am able to make the substitution for the most part. However, I always find that the second entry of the dictionary ("02-more text") is always in the otherwise sanitized output file.

What am I doing wrong? I've read that Python doesn't like to make substitutions to a list it is iterating through. So, I have a new list to which the 'for loop' appends. Within that I have a 'temp row' that copies the row within the original "csv_rows".

Why is "02-more text" always in the output file?

The original file is a CSV file. Turning the dataframe 'tolist' makes each row of the dataframe a list within a larger list, 'csv_rows'.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv 
from csv import writer

dictionary = {
"01-some text" : "replacement",
"02-more text" : "replacement",
"03-even more text" : "replacement",
"01-text" : "replacement",
"02-another lorem" : "replacement",
"03-ipsum" : "replacement",
"04-dolorem" : "replacement"
}

def append_list_as_row(file_name, list_of_elem):
    # Open file in append mode
    with open(file_name, 'a+', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as write_obj:
        # Create a writer object from csv module
        csv_writer = writer(write_obj)
        # Add contents of list as last row in the csv file
        csv_writer.writerow(list_of_elem)

def get_file_encoding(src_file_path):
    """
    Get the encoding type of a file
    :param src_file_path: file path
    :return: str - file encoding type
    """
    with open(src_file_path) as src_file:
        return src_file.encoding

data = 'ANQAR.csv'
my_encoding = str(get_file_encoding(data))
df = pd.read_csv(data, encoding=my_encoding)

csv_rows = df.values.tolist()
new_list = []

for key in dictionary:  
    for row in csv_rows:
        temp_row = row
        if key in row:
            #find the index
            i = row.index(key)
            #replace value with new one
            temp_row[i] = dictionary[key]
        new_list.append(temp_row)


for row in new_list:
    append_list_as_row('newANQAR.csv', row)
```

Comment: You're making a new row in `new_list` for each key in the dictionary, whether or not it made a replacement. So each row in the original file will be multiplied 7 times.

Comment: **I've read that Python doesn't like to make substitutions to a list it is iterating through** You misunderstood. You shouldn't insert or remove from the list, but modifying the list elements themselves is fine.

Comment: Please share the current and expected output, as well as a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't doing the sanitizing properly.

Try running the following snippet and see if it works for you:

```
replacements_map = {
    "01-some text": "replacement",
    "02-more text": "replacement",
    "03-even more text": "replacement",
    "01-text": "replacement",
    "02-another lorem": "replacement",
    "03-ipsum": "replacement",
    "04-dolorem": "replacement"
}

csv_rows = [["01-some text", " other data here"],
            ["wont need replacement", "02-another lorem"]]

sanitized_rows = []

for row in csv_rows:
    sanitized_rows.append(
        [(replacements_map[item] if (item in replacements_map) else item)
         for item
         in row]
    )

print(sanitized_rows)
```

Comment: The list comprehension seems to have done it. Thanks!